# Ace: move caret into the pair of brackets after custom autocompletion

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, ace-editor

I am new to Ace and I am making a JavaScript editor with it. I added autocompleters to the editor:

```
var functionCompleter = {
    getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
        var funcList = ["foo", "bar"]
        callback(null, funcList.map(function(word) {
            return {
                caption: word,
                value: word + "()",
                meta: "Custom Functions"
            };
        }));
    }
}
editor.completers.push(functionCompleter);
```

After autocompletion:

[image]

However I want the caret to be between the round brackets after completing, like this:

[image]

so that it would be more convenient to add function parameters

Is there anyway to do it in JavaScript? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the auto-completion, you could set the cursor in between the brackets using goToLine function of Ace.

```
//Once you Insert the brackets ()
var pos = editor.selection.getCursor(); //Take the latest position on the editor
editor.gotoLine(pos.row + 1, pos.column + 2); //This will set your cursor in between the brackets
```

For the callback you could use the autocompletes **insertMatch**

```
var functionCompleter = {
    getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
        var funcList = ["foo", "bar"]
        callback(null, funcList.map(function(word) {
            return {
                caption: word,
                value: word + "()",
                meta: "Custom Functions"

                completer: {
                    insertMatch: function(editor, data) {
                        console.log(data.value); // This should give the completed keyword
                        // Here you can get the position and set the cursor
                    }
                }
            };
        }));
    }
}
editor.completers.push(functionCompleter);
```

Comment: I know that we can move the cursor using JavaScript, but how can we get the callback function when the user selects an autocomplete option?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the answer to support with callback. Please check

Comment: The completed keyword doesn't even show up. How can I fix that?

Comment: Updated the answer. The data.value would give you the complete keyword

Comment: I mean that the completed word won't insert into the ace editor

Comment: Do you want to add the keyword inside the brackets?

Comment: Even the brackets and the word before it doesn’t show up

Comment: Add this After `console.log(data.value)`: 
`editor.session.insert(editor.getCursorPosition(), data.value);` this will insert the autocomplete suggestion into the editor, to move cursor all you have to do is 
`editor.gotoLine(pos.row + 1, pos.column + data.value.length - 2);` which moves two places behind the line ending, hence inside brackets (`here`);